# AJAX (prototype/java) getting partial status updates during execution

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

This partially mimics [AJAX (prototype/php) getting partial status updates during script execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800997/ajax-prototype-php-getting-partial-status-updates-during-script-execution), however I'm working with JSP pages and servlets. What I want to do is start an action when the user clicks a button and then present updates on the progress of this action. The action can take anywhere from 1 to 10 minutes to complete, so I don't want the user just sitting on the screen waiting for a response but rather display a status bar or something denoting what part of the action the transaction is on.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run and control a long-running process, better let it run in its own `Thread` instead of the request's `Thread`. Store a reference to this `Thread` in the session scope so that the client can use ajaxical requests (using the same session!) to request the server side for the current progress (and automagically also to keep the session alive so that it doesn't timeout).

Here's a basic example of such a servlet:

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class RunLongProcessServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        if ("XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("x-requested-with"))) {
            LongProcess longProcess = (LongProcess) request.getSession().getAttribute("longProcess");
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().write(String.valueOf(longProcess.getProgress()));
        } else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("runLongProcess.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        LongProcess longProcess = new LongProcess();
        longProcess.setDaemon(true);
        longProcess.start();
        request.getSession().setAttribute("longProcess", longProcess);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("runLongProcess.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}

class LongProcess extends Thread {

    private int progress;

    public void run() {
        while (progress < 100) {
            try { sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
            progress++;
        }
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

}
```

..which is mapped as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>runLongProcess</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.RunLongProcessServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>runLongProcess</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/runLongProcess</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here's a basic example of the JSP (with a little shot [jQuery](http://jquery.com), an ajaxical JS framework which I by the way greatly recommend):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Show progress of long running process with help of Thread and Ajax.</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(init);

            function init() {
                if (${not empty longProcess}) {
                    $.progress = 0;
                    checkProgress();
                }
            }

            function checkProgress() {
                $.getJSON('runLongProcess', function(progress) {
                    $('#progress').text(progress);
                    $.progress = parseInt(progress);
                });
                if ($.progress < 100) {
                    setTimeout(checkProgress, 1000);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="runLongProcess" method="post">
            <p>Run long process: <input type="submit"></p>
            <p>Current status: <span id="progress">0</span>%</p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Open it at http://localhost:8080/yourcontext/runLongProcess and click the button.

If this is a really, really long running process, you may improve "efficiency" by increasing the ajax request intervals in the `setTimeout()` to 5 seconds (5000 ms) or so, so that the server doesn't feel getting DDOS'ed ;)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for necroposting... Doesn't `request.getSession().setAttribute("longProcess", longProcess);` leak memory? Even after the thread finishes, you maintain a reference in the session object. Maybe I don't understand how session attributes work?

Answer (score 1):

You may like [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html). With help of DWR you could make async requests to the server to get information about the progress of the specific job.